# Partition using recursion

Tags: haskell

Trying to learn myself some haskell, I know about the function

```
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

would I be able to this using recursion rather than using the function. eg id have my own defined function

```
partition':: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

which would use recursion

Comment: What is your question? Have you actually tried an approach yet?

Comment: im trying to implement a similar function to partition but uses recursion instead. The question is to slits two lists according to a function parsed int he command line eg partition' even [1,2,3,4,5] would return ([2,4],[1,3,5])

Comment: recursion is not the key for everything, partition with just 2 filtering operations is much easier to understand

Comment: @DanielSanchez The OP is likely studying recursion through this exercise. Also, filtering twice means going through the list a second time unnecessarily. (A single-pass partition can be done via `foldr`, but I digress.)

Comment: @duplode yes that's right so far i've got a basic recursive format but having trouble adding the elements from down the recursive train into the list that would be printed out at the end

Comment: @duplode, I know that a single pass with a foldr would be enough, but recursively achive this is stil ineficient, so its better to understand what it is doing and how, I was just pointing this.

Comment: @DanielSanchez If we expand the `foldr` solution by substituting the definition of `foldr` we get a no less efficient recursive definition along the lines of zerkms' suggestion above.

Comment: @duplode are you sure about it? Not same performance  within fold and recursive, anyway doing it recursively is still a good exercise :)

Comment: @DanielSanchez I'm not sure about which difference you are refering to. Substituting the definition of `foldr` in [`Data.List.partition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-OldList.html#partition) reveals the same algorithm Oded used in their answer -- the only differences are minutiae such as the lazy pattern match in the fold-operation.

Comment: @duplode, im not saying you are not right, in fact is a pretty interesting topic, i've test that using fold vs solve problems doing recursion manually tend to speed the execution times (Some compiler magic?), may we talk privately so you can explain it properly?

Comment: @DanielSanchez There are a few tricks (`INLINE` pragmas, [rewrite rules](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html), etc.) that can make the `foldr` solution faster when used in a broader context, as you describe. And it is indeed a good idea to avoid writing recursion explicitly in real code, not just due to performance gains but also as a matter of style. I only insisted a little further in that point so that the OP wouldn't end up think that, given just what we had written here up to that point, the explicitly recursive algorithm was less efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one recursive definition:

```
partition':: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
partition' _ [] = ([],[])
partition' f (x:xs) | f x = (x:matched,notMatched)
                    | otherwise = (matched,x:notMatched)
                    where (matched,notMatched) = partition' f xs
```